# Least Squares solution for a matrix and orthogonal matrix

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares

Let matrix $A$ be a real $n \times n$ matrix, $Q$ be an orthogonal real $n \times n$ matrix.

Let $V\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $V\neq 0$

I am trying to find the following two least squares solutions to:

1. $\min_{\mu\in \mathbb{R}} \| AV - \mu V \|_2^2$
2. $\min_{\mu\in \mathbb{R}} \| \mu QV - V \|_2^2$

Comment: Note that $\|x\|^2 = x^T x$. This will give you a quadratic in $\mu$.

Comment: @copper.hat I am aware of this particular method of solving, but I was told by my professor that I was working too hard and there is a fast and easy way to solve it. I’m not sure what I missed. Does anything jump out at you?

Comment: Let $\phi(\mu) = AV-\mu V$, then it is the composition of $\|\cdot \|^2$ and $\phi$. Set the derivative (from the chain rule) to zero and see what you get. I should have thought of that earlier.

Comment: @copper.hat Oh, that makes sense. Good catch. Check me on this... I followed your steps and got that it minimizes for $\mu=A$ in the first and $\mu=Q^{-1}$ in the second. I just realized that $\mu$ is just a scalar though, so I must be wrong somehow.

Comment: @copper.hat I got $0=2(AV-\mu V)^T(-V)$ for my derivative

Comment: From that you can compute the minimising $\mu$ directly.

Comment: Remember $A$ is a matrix. $\mu = { v^TAv \over v^T v }$ for the first.

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks! I figured out the first one. For the second value I got $\frac{V^TQ^TV}{||QV||}$. Does that seem right? Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: Looks good. One more thing, since $Q$ is orthogonal, $\|QV\| = \|V\|$. (This could also have been simplified in the derivative condition, noting that $Q^T Q = I$.)

Comment: Also, since $Q$ is orthogonal, we have $\|\mu Q V -V\| = \|\mu V - Q^T V\|$, so you could reduce the second to the first with $A= Q^T$. Also, since we are in the reals, $x^T Q^T x = x^T Q x$.